# Google Drive Android REST V3 Dependencies Clash

Tags: android, google-drive-api

So I want these dependencies to make requests to drive using v3 API :
[image]

But this error appears when I include them

[image]

Even though I am using exclude group , This would't let me generate a release apk unless I have set abortOnError false

Any idea how to get rid of it ?

Comment: Your version 1.23.0 is very old, try to update to 1.31.0

Comment: I want to get rid of that warning , updated the version to 1.31.0 , The warning hasn't gone , One more question , how did you find the latest version , it gives no warning to update the version in gradle file and its hard to find something on google !

Comment: I have to revert to previous version , That version could not be resolved